# Why does this fail with Msg 41317: A user transaction that accesses memory optimized tables

Tags: sql-server

```
use WorldWideImporters;
go

Changed database context to 'WorldWideImporters'.

select name, is_memory_optimized 
from sys.tables 
where is_memory_optimized = 1;
go

name                       is_memory_optimized
----------------------------------------------
ColdRoomTemperatures               1
VehicleTemperatures                1
```

The `WorldWideImporters` database contains two memory optimized tables.

However when I try this

```
create database foo;
go

select * 
into foo.dbo.ColdRoomTemperatures_Archive 
from ColdRoomTemperatures_Archive;
go
```

I get this:

> Msg 41317, Level 16, State 3, Server 670dd29ba44a, Line 1
> A user transaction that accesses memory optimized tables or natively compiled modules cannot access more than one user database or databases model and msdb, and it cannot write to master.

Which does make not make any sense to me since `ColdRoomTemperatures_archived` is not a memory optimized table according to `sys.tables`. What am I missing here?

Comment: select @@trancount?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4459327/fix-error-41317-when-you-enable-server-audit-and-you-use-in-memory-tra

Comment: @lptr In effect a single user database, there are no other users of the database. Not sure what @@trancount would have to do with anything anyway. A little explnation would help.

Comment: FYI this is running on the latest docker images for SQL Server 207 and 2019 on Linux.

Comment: @gotqn. Nothing to do with article you referenced. I totally fail to understand why you even referenced it other than it happens to have the same Error in it.